# How to correctly combine Using and WhenTypeIs<DateTime> in Fluent Assertions

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have a dictionary of objects like so: `Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();`

Within the dictionary is a `DateTime`, I am trying test if that `DateTime` falls on a particular day, like so:

```
Attributes[key].ShouldBeEquivalentTo(DateTime.Now, options => options
    .Using<DateTime>(ctx =>
    {
        //throw new InvalidOperationException();
        ctx.Subject.Should().BeSameDateAs(ctx.Expectation);
    }).WhenTypeIs<DateTime>());
```

However this results in the failed assertion `Expected subject to be <2016-06-30 11:38:05.447>, but found <2016-06-30 10:38:05>`. The dates are on the same date so I believe should pass, but the assertion has failed.

This leads me to conclude that the line `ctx.Subject.Should().BeSameDateAs(ctx.Expectation)` is not being applied. I tried adding an exception, and debugging but it appears the code in the action is never reached.

Should I expect this work? I am doing this correctly?

Comment: I don't know this API, so this is just a guess: try `options.WhenTypeIs<DateTime>().Using<DateTime>(...)`

Comment: so basically you're trying to test a `DateTime` stored in `object`?

Comment: @AlekseyL. pretty much, I suppose I should add that not `object` will be a `DateTime`.

Comment: @JamesWood one of the properties of an object will be a `DateTime`? can you add specific example?

Comment: @AlekseyL. Sorry, I didn't word that very well, I meant that the collection might also contain something other than a `DateTime`, e.g. an `string`. The above is a cut down version of my original problem where I was trying to selectively compare values from two collections. I actually solved that problem in a different way. In any case your answer would seem to accurately address the use of `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` which is what this question was about. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in action is never reached because `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` is supposed to compare object graph (properties of actual and expected). `Using...WhenTypeIs<DateTime>` will be applied to **properties** of type `DateTime`.

In your case object is `DateTime` itself, so you can assert that it is indeed `DateTime` and chain other required assertions:

```
Attributes[key].Should().BeOfType<DateTime>().Which.Should().BeSameDateAs(DateTime.Now);
```